# Run local python script on remote machine

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote, remote-control

I wish to run python script that I have locally on disk on remote machine. I used to run bash scripts like this:

```
cat script.sh | ssh user@machine
```

but I do not know how to do same for Python script.

Comment: `cat script.py | ssh user@machine python`

Comment: Or see `ansible` for a somewhat more complicated take on the run-code-via-SSH thing.

Comment: Copy the script to the server and run it.

Comment: @jordanm How do I pass parameters to script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, pipe it into ssh.  But what you will want to do is give the proper arguments.  You will want to add `-u` to get the output back from ssh properly.  And want to add `-` to handle the output and later arguments.

```
ssh user@host python -u - < script.py
```

If you want to give command line arguments, add them after the `-`.

```
ssh user@host python -u - --opt arg1 arg2 < script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the remrunner package for python.
It copies local scripts to a remote machine and then executes them.

`pip install remrunner`

```
python
>> from rumrunner import runner

>> r = runner.Runner(REMOTE_HOST_IPADDR, REMOTE_HOST_USER)
>> rval, stdout, stderr = r.run('/path/to/local/script.py')
>> if rval:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```